# SeaORM: The connection string 'sqlite://test.db' has no supporting driver

Tags: rust, sea-orm

Using sea-orm-cli to generate a database using `sea-orm-cli migrate` but this gives the error

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
> value: Conn("The connection string 'sqlite://test.db' has no
> supporting driver.")',
> .../.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sea-orm-migration-0.8.3/src/cli.rs:17:45

Anything missing here? The cargo.toml contains the sqlite features so I'd assume this should work.

```
sea-orm = { version = "0.8.0", features = [ "sqlx-mysql", "sqlx-sqlite", "runtime-tokio-rustls", "macros", "debug-print", "mock" ] }
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure that the `DATABASE_DRIVER` and `ASYNC_RUNTIME` is also included in `./migration/cargo.toml`.